# Website really lagging in Firefox, and a little in Safari / Chrome (First time trying animations with css3 and jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, animation, lag

Some weeks ago I started with the development of a new personal portfolio-website. I'm happy with the interface now, but the animations are sooooo laggy (especially at Firefox). I tried to find the problem for days now but I can't find it. Can someone take a look at it for me?

About the site:
You can slide horizontal and vertically by using a mousedown and drag function.

When the site gets laggy:

1. On page load - when the projects are sliding in
2. When mousedown and drag
3. On the 'List-button-click'

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    //Fade in projects
    $('#projects ul').children().each(function(i){
        $(this).delay(i*50).stop().animate({opacity: "1"}, 800);
    });
    
    //Show project images
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#projects li').each(function(i){
            var t = $(this);
            setTimeout(function(){ t.addClass('projectsSlidein'); }, (i+1) * 50);
        });
    }, 1000);
    
    //When mouse down - scale projects
    $('#projects').mousedown(function() {
        $('#projects').addClass('animateSmall');
    });
    
    //When mouse up - scale projects back to normal size
    $('#projects').mouseup(function() {
        $('#projects').removeClass('animateSmall');
    });
    
    //When hover project - Show image
    $('#projects li').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('projectsSlidein');
    });
    
    //When leave project - Hide image
    $('#projects li').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).addClass('projectsSlidein');
    });

});

//Drag and scroll function
$(function(){
    var curDown = false,
      curYPos = 0,
      curXPos = 0;
    $('#projects').mousemove(function(m){
    if(curDown === true){
     $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + (curYPos - m.pageY)); 
     $(window).scrollLeft($(window).scrollLeft() + (curXPos - m.pageX));
    }
    });

    $('#projects').mousedown(function(m){
    curDown = true;
    curYPos = m.pageY;
    curXPos = m.pageX;
    });

    $('#projects').mouseup(function(){
    curDown = false;
    });
});
```

```css
li {
    list-style: none;
}

#projects {
    width: 3500px;
    height: 2100px;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

#cursor.animateSmall {
    transform: scale(0.5) !important;
}

#projects.animateSmall {
    transform: scale(1.0) !important;
}

#cursor.animateBig {
    transform: scale(2.5);
}

#projects ul {
    width: 4500px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -500px;
    margin-top: -100px;
}


#projects ul:first-of-type li, #projects ul:last-of-type li {
    opacity: 0.2 !important;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) !important;
    filter: grayscale(100%) !important;
    pointer-events: none !important;
}

#projects li {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
    background-color: #333;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    background-image: url(http://dev2.iamfrank.eu/images/portfolio/campus/cover.jpg);
    border: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}

.projectsSlidein {
    background-position: bottom !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

#projects ul li:first-of-type { 
    opacity: 0.2 !important;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) !important;
    filter: grayscale(100%) !important;
    pointer-events: none !important;
}

#projects ul li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    opacity: 0.2  !important;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%)  !important;
    filter: grayscale(100%)  !important;
    pointer-events: none !important;
}

#projects li:nth-child(even) {margin-top: 50px;}
#projects li:nth-child(odd) {margin-top: -200px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>  
    <section id="projects">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Much appreciated!

Frank (just a newbie)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Hello @j08691. Thanks for your message. I just added a snipped. Hopefully this is helping out! Frank